# Dock and Top Bar flashing non-stop at fullscreen

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, top-bar

This problem affects all extensions that alter the dock and top bar. Including the standard extension "Ubuntu dock". All extensions are duly updated to the present date.

I hoped that when entering full screen it would be possible to bring the dock and the top bar when placing the mouse over the respective corners. And in fact it is partially possible.

However, both are flashing, making it impossible to use them in full screen. They blink very fast and you need to click on the correct timing to open the programs on the dock, for example. It is possible to click, but it is as if they were triggered several times, as if I were placing and removing the mouse from the corner very quickly.

I enter the program. Everything is OK. The problem arises when I use the fullscreen. Sometimes the docks and the top bar work perfectly for a while, and then they start flashing.

Comment: First debug your extensions: turn all extensions off except the default ones. Also provide info on your hardware (graphics card, drivers)

Comment: All extensions have been uninstalled. The problem persists. The problem also happens on two different graphics cards.

Comment: Add information relevant to solving your question to the questionitself: use "edit". Comments may disappear or may be missed.